# Unexpected behavior of svg draggable/panzoom

Tags: svg, svg.js

I need to use svg.js 3 with draggable and panzoom plugins. What I need to do is create some shapes and group it together and then attach draggable to entire group.
This is the code I managed so far:

```
var canvas = SVG()
    .addTo('#svg-canvas')
    .size($(window).width(), $(window).height())
    .viewbox('0 0 ' + $(window).width() + ' ' + $(window).height())
    .panZoom({
        zoomFactor: 0.1,
        wheelZoom: true,
        zoomMin: 0.25,
        zoomMax: 4
    })
    .zoom(2);


const headerHeight = 40;
const rowHeight = 24;
const radius = 4;
const borderTop = 1
const margin = 2;

const table = canvas.group();

const tableWrapper = canvas.rect(200, headerHeight).fill("#fff");
tableWrapper.radius(radius);
table.add(tableWrapper);

const headerWrapper = canvas.rect(200, headerHeight - radius).fill("transparent");
headerWrapper.move(0, radius);
table.add(headerWrapper);

const headerContent = canvas.foreignObject(200, headerHeight - radius);
headerContent.move(0, radius);

headerContent.add($('\
    <div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;display:flex;padding:8px;margin-top:-1px;">\
        <div>Header</div>\
        <div>PK</div>\
    </div>\
')[0]);
table.add(headerContent);

tableWrapper.height(44);

table.move(180, 150);

table.draggable();
```

Here is jsfiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/grayter/uhde3ykw/29/

The problem is that when I try to drag group the content of the group is flowing. I suppose that panzoom plugin is the reason of that behavior (it seems like draggable and panzoom `drag` event are interfering).

What am I missing? Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't know what "flowing" means in this context so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Did you see jsfiddle? When you start drag white box text will move 2 times faster and eventually will be outside the dragged box.

Comment: This is a chrome only issue. In FF it works flawlessly. Try the newest master branch (git clone + npm run build) and report back if it is fixed there

Comment: @Fuzzyma I will try that but the problem is that my client demand to not use npm and any other package library so eventually I need to use bundled version.

Comment: Thats exactly what you get when you clone the repo and run npm run build. It will put all bundled files into the /dist/ folder. Beside that, this is only to check if it might be fixed already

Comment: @Fuzzyma I downloaded and create dist for draggable and unfortunately problem still exists.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear. I meant the newest master of svg.js itself

Comment: Nope, still not working on chrome. There is some no significant difference but problem remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212780/discussion-between-fuzzyma-and-adam-mrozek).